# Removing & re-adding a plugin leaves out iOS project file modifications etc. - how to workaround?

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, phonegap-plugins

Removing & re-adding a plugin leaves out iOS project file modifications etc.
- re-adding via command line: cordova add/rm plugin

There was a similar issue fixed in 3.4.0.
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4971

We're still experiencing this issue in Cordova 3.5.0

Anyone knows a workaround? Why does this appear in 3.5.0 still though it should be fixed in 3.4.0?

Comment: I am also getting similar issues in cordova 3.6 version too